# Creating a sequence of functions using the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Let $A$ be a countable set. 
> Use the axiom of choice to prove the
> existence of a function sequence $\langle h_{k} \space | \space 1 \leq k \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$ s.t for each $k$, 
>  $h_k: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A^{k}$ is a bijection.

Well, I know that since the set $A$ is countable then if we consider the set of all bijections  from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A^{k}$ for some $k$, (which exists by separation), it isn't empty and we can pick one using the axiom. Specifically, I struggle with the technique part, which is to figure what should be the domain set for the choice function. I only could think of taking $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain set and this way we can create a sequence but I cant see how to it link with A elements.

I'd like to have some advice. (I know it is also can be proved using recursion but I'm asked to use the axiom of choice particularly).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the axiom of choice here, of course. You can simply construct these bijections by composing and iterating the bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $A$, as well as $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N^2$.

The exercise, I suppose, is to argue that $A^k$ is countable for all $k\in\Bbb N$, and it is countably infinite when $k>0$. Which means that the set $B_k=\{f\colon\Bbb N\to A^k\mid f\text{ is a bijection}\}$ is non-empty. Therefore, $\{B_k\mid 1\leq k\}$ is a family of non-empty sets, so using the axiom of choice, we can choose $h_k\in B_k$, which is exactly to say that there is a sequence $\langle h_k\mid 1\leq k\rangle$ as wanted.

Of course, you seem to have noticed that, and you also seem to have noticed that using the axiom of choice here is unnecessary.

Comment: So by using recursion we can explicitly construct the functions without arguing that $A^k$ is countable for each $k \geq 1 $? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, it's kinda how you prove that each $A^k$ is countable, if you think about it.

Comment: The proof that I've seen is constructing a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^{2}$ and then using induction to prove for $\mathbb{N}^k$. Is that the idea? Since I still dont see how I explicitly use the given bijection to construct recursively other than for the base case

Comment: Yes. That is the idea.